# Django middleware skipping data attribute in static url

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, push-notification, django-views

i have a simple middleware builded in django app. It works for push notification image tracking. Logic: if push shows up, middleware should see it by data attribute and update status of my Push object. 
My middleware code:

```
class PushStatistic:
    def process_request(self, request):
        if request.GET.get('pushid'):
            print('entered push id for readed')
            pushid = request.GET.get('pushid')
            print(f'Push id - {pushid}. Updating...')
            if pushid:
                pushid = int(pushid)
                if Push.objects.filter(id=pushid).exists():
                    Push.objects.filter(id=pushid).update(status=4)
                    print('status updated')
```

so when i send notification, icon url for push looks like this:

```
https://test.com/static/img/pic.png?pushid=9403687
```

When push showing up, i see the picture, but middleware not working.

I use the same middleware logic for push-clicks tracking, and it works well. I cant understand what im doing wrong now, cause as i see it, its just the same GET request. Maybe its because its static url?

Also i build django-view with same logic for push tracking AND IN VIEW IT WORKS:

```
def fileresp(request, filename):
    if request.GET.get('pushid'):
        pushid = request.GET.get('pushid')
        Push.objects.filter(id=pushid).update(status=4)


    image_data = open(f"{project_settings.BASE_DIR}/media/{filename}", "rb").read()
    return HttpResponse(image_data, content_type="image/png")
```

But i want to build it in django-middleware for more universality. Is it possible?

Comment: "Middleware not working" what do you mean by this ? Is there an error message, or any log ? Or do you just don't get the update ?

Comment: Push object just not updating, "prints" are not showing up in logs

Comment: Which version of Django are you using? Django middleware is not designed like that anymore

Comment: Django==1.11.4. Unfortuanally i cant update it right now, cause whole project is really old, and still have a lot of old logic stuff

Comment: Middleware has long since changed, even for 1.11 https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/middleware/#writing-your-own-middleware

Answer (score 1):

In production, you normally configure your server (e.g. Apache or Nginx) to serve the static/media files, or use a CDN. Therefore the Django doesn't handle the request for static files, so the middleware doesn't run.

If you must run this middleware for static files, you could consider using [whitenoise](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/django.html) to serve static files. You would need to put your middleware class above `WhiteNoiseMiddleware`, despite the warnings in the whitenoise docs not to do that.

Comment: You could also mirror the traffic from your server to an other route designed only to do the update. Using https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_mirror_module.html for example.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your middleware to a design [supported by the version of Django you are using](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/middleware/#writing-your-own-middleware)

```
class PushStatistic(object):

    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        if request.GET.get('pushid'):
            print('entered push id for readed')
            pushid = request.GET.get('pushid')
            print(f'Push id - {pushid}. Updating...')
            if pushid:
                pushid = int(pushid)
                if Push.objects.filter(id=pushid).exists():
                    Push.objects.filter(id=pushid).update(status=4)
                    print('status updated')

        response = self.get_response(request)

        return response
```

Comment: Django 1.11 supports `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` and `MIDDLEWARE`. It's a good idea to upgrade, but the old-style middleware isn't what's causing the problem here.

Comment: @IainShelvington for me process_request worked. I have not any problems with middleware config, the problem is only push-update logic. For clicks i use same middleware, and it works well. So i dont think that the problem is in middleware design

Comment: You need to subclass [`django.utils.deprecation.MiddlewareMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/middleware/#django.utils.deprecation.MiddlewareMixin) if you want to use process_request

Comment: @Alasdair it does, but only if the middleware subclasses the deprecation class

Comment: If the settings is using `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` instead of `MIDDLEWARE`, then the mixin isn't required in Django 1.10/1.11.